# How to prevent validation trigger before submitting form

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am using bootstrap validation but its triggering before I submit the form.

Below is my code that I am calling in my load function .

```
 <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-2 NoteType disableAll" id="NoteTypeDiv">
                            <label class="control-label" for="NoteType">Note Type<span class="required">*</span></label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="NoteType" name="NoteType" ddlist="" onchange="Clinical_Notes.GetNotesTemplates();">
                                <option selected="selected" value="">-Select-</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
```

**JS Code:-**

```
ValidateNotes: function (FrmCtrl) {       
    $('#' + Clinical_Notes.params.PanelID + '#frmClinicalNotes').bootstrapValidator('destroy');
    $('#' + FrmCtrl)
      .bootstrapValidator({
          live: 'disabled',
          message: 'This value is not valid',
          feedbackIcons: {
              valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
              invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
              validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
          },
          fields: {
                  NoteType: {
                      group: '.col-sm-4',
                      validators: {
                          notEmpty: {
                              message: ''
                          },
                      }
                  },
                }
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: can you create a fiddle for it.. I tried to so so and its showing some dependencies... https://jsfiddle.net/vikash2402/0dbgzw42/1/

Comment: don't know about that

Comment: onchange="Clinical_Notes.GetNotesTemplates();"> do u know about Clinical_Notes... if yes then add that.. then only any one can change the value of dropdown and check why its happening.. add complete/proper code so that whoever is helping you get a fair idea..... else best of luck...

Comment: u can add hardcode dropdown values @Developerrr

Comment: woww man.. you are expecting help but not ready to help youself.. i mean you should have created a working sample and then added here instead of asking others.... (y)

Comment: though i tried to create a fiddle for you but u didn't have curtsy to check and validate or do required changes.. you are saying "don't know about that"

Comment: well, I have added an answer see if it can be useful for u...

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is an additional attribute ***`trigger`*** in bootstarp validator you can try that.

[image]

You can choose the options when you want to trigger the validator.

```
$('#update-form').bootstrapValidator({
    trigger: 'blur', // change values here
    fields: {}
});
```

**Similar sample:-** http://jsfiddle.net/vikash2402/x7pooh99/12/

**Validation on Submit:-** https://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator/issues/240

***Hoping this will help you:)***

Comment: you are welcome... btw exactly when you want to trigger bootstrap validation besically..

Comment: i want to trigger it on submit (button click)

Comment: thanks alot for your help .but now my problem's logic has been changed ):

Comment: if above answer satisfy the given question then accept it as answer.. and post the new logic as new question and will look into that...